# window.history.go() not loading previous user input for dynamically created dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having this issue where I have a table that depending on what option I select for the first column, the next column which contains a drop down, will populate with the appropriate values that users can select.

Here's an example

[image: Two different drop downs dynamically created from two different options in the first column]

When the user submits the form, they're brought to a results page and have the option of going back to the first screen (where they select the drop downs etc).

Currently, I'm using the `window.history.go()` function to go back to the previous pages.  However, the dynamically created drop downs aren't retaining the value that the user selects (the option that is at the very top of the drop down is always selected).

I'm currently using PHP for the scripts to generate the tables.  Is there a way to fix this?  Just need someone to point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use history.pushstate(url+'#idx=x') when dropdown changes. and load the param values into dropdown when page loaded

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'm currently looking into how to implement it.